# Why doesnt SD have an icon?

Tags: feature-request, design

Why doesnt SD have an icon and a fancy background like other sites

Sorry if thats a stupid question but i was wondering.

Does it have to do with the traffic?

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: [Custom Sound Design Community design and logo - Information gathering](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1477/34208) :)

Comment: Update: [New site design launched](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497/34208) (which includes a new logo and favicon!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is a beta.  Beta sites don't get much in the way of graphic design and CSS work.  When a site graduates from beta, SE staff go through and create a custom theme for it.

Comment: cool! thanks! when is it coming out of beta ?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. SE staff decide based on their impression of how a site is doing.

Comment: I see, well let's hope for the best! :D

Comment: If it ever *does* pass the Beta phase, would the moderators (or community) have a say on the graphics; like the icon and element design then?