# New site design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new site design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

I have enjoyed working with you to create this theme. Thank you for being engaged in the process, and I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: Reminder: the site design [supports dark mode](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1492/11100) ;) "*If you add the `theme-dark` class to the body HTML, you will see [Sound.SE in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx2WT.png)*"

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @paintedbicycle - it really works well for me!

Haven't tried dark mode yet, but I'm loving it - haven't yet memorised the favicon (used to SD) but by tomorrow I probably will have it :-)

Awesome work

Answer (score 2):

Liking it.

I also like the background which you can't ordinarily see. I had a tiny network glitch which made just the background appear for half a second before the page drew over it - ooh, swirly ;))

One oddity - not a bug, it just briefly poked at my OCD.
You kind of get used, these days, to seeing numbers next to dials, reflecting the parameter, which just made this look slightly odd…

[image]

So… the first dial is only on or off, second goes up to maybe 24, third… well into the hundreds ;))

Comment: Ha, yes, it was supposed to be "low", "medium" and "11" in my mind. If there ends up being a consensus that it needs to change I can update it

Comment: @paintedbicycle -  Sure, it does make perfect sense… my OCD just thought it clashed with the numbers. There's no way it could ever be any different… unless you were going to make 127 versions of each ;)))

Comment: The numbers lol - It's fine. Imagine they are negative threshold numbers or something ha!. I don't even get an 11-knob :( Goto work harder!

Answer (score 2):

### Thank you so much @paintedbicycle and the team!

I LOVE dark mode, I really wish there was a DM option in preferences. It's so nice, I want it permanently on.

**Now, with *total respect*, I do have *only a couple* of thoughts -**

1. When I go into dark mode, the wave goes weird - am I doing it right?
   [image: Dark mode try-out]
2. This icon ***colour*** - [image: Our current tab icon] - I didn't see this in the [draft](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/site-design-and-logo-draft), If I did, I would have suggested something more like the meta icon [image: SD meta tab icon] but coloured green, like [image: Network Engineering logo] did with their blue (if the icon is too small to have something like the full or partial [image: SD site logo] colours). I'm just really not keen on the red, but if nothing can be done, I'll live!
3. This is 2.5 really; Our logo is still the old one in a few places ([stackexchange.com sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) and [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=sound.stackexchange.com)):
   [image: Logo currently on SE site list] [image: SD logo in chat]

Thoughts: OUT!
Thanks again, and thanks for reading!

Comment: "This is 2.5 really; Our logo is still the old one in a few places:" – Where? I'm guessing at least one of the places you're talking about the grid view of the sites list on stackexchange.com, which [now appears updated for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XmRp.png) (albeit slightly different from the version on the main site). ...And [your last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zMG2.png) seems to be pretty close to [the site logo shown in the chat header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAeFb.png)

Comment: Yeah, I did put more info in the tooltips. It's still the same on the site list and in chat for me. Must just need more time.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and reloading the stackexchange.com/sites page? I'll follow up internally as well.

Comment: It prob just needs time, I tried it in a private browser but still the same.

Comment: Yep, looks like [caching is indeed to blame](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) (on the CDN's end, not the browser cache). That should hopefully resolve itself within a few days.